Memory leaks with UMDF2 driver
Our self developed umdf2 driver is working pretty well, but with every request the umdf framework is allactation a memory block without freeing it. (around 512 bytes).
Any idea?
Here is the stack:
ntdll.dll!QueryRegistryValue() - Zeile 0
WUDFx02000.dll!FxDevice::AllocateRequestMemory() - Zeile 1716
WUDFx02000.dll!FxRequest::_CreateForPackage() - Zeile 118
WUDFx02000.dll!FxPkgIo::DispatchStep2() - Zeile 392
WUDFx02000.dll!FxPkgIo::DispatchStep1() - Zeile 338
WUDFx02000.dll!DispatchWorker() - Zeile 1590
WUDFHost.exe!CWudfIoIrp::Dispatch() - Zeile 875
WUDFHost.exe!CWudfDeviceStack::Forward() - Zeile 2815
WUDFHost.exe!CLpcNotification::Message() - Zeile 1217
WUDFPlatform.dll!WdfLpcPort::ProcessMessage() - Zeile 349
WUDFPlatform.dll!WdfLpcCommPort::ProcessMessage() - Zeile 695
WUDFPlatform.dll!WdfLpcConnPort::ProcessMessage() - Zeile 180
WUDFPlatform.dll!WdfLpc::RetrieveMessage() - Zeile 189
WUDFHost.exe!ThreadPoolWorkerThunk() - Zeile 23
ntdll.dll!TppExecuteWaitCallback() - Zeile 0
ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread() - Zeile 0
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() - Zeile 0

I have no idea how to fix it.
